# Processmaker 4 comunity customize forms to display a pdf

Tags: processmaker

I am trying the dockerized version of processmaker for (https://github.com/ProcessMaker/pm4core-docker) I need to create a form in which half of the screen is used to visualize the PDF document that must be aproved.
I read that in previous versions of Processmaker there was the option to add some custom javascript to a Dynaform, but I am unable to find such option in version 4.

Is it possible to embed a pdf view in the comunity version of processmaker 4?

Answer (score 2):

I have just figured out that it is quite easy to add any custom HTML by using the rich text element. In this case I could embed the PDF simply by typing the Html code:

```
<embed src="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" width="800px" height="900px" />
```

Now the question is .. how can I do it so that the PDF that is displayed is a file uploaded to a specific workflow.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I'm sure it will help others!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the File Preview option to display a file that was previously uploaded to a request by pointing it to the request variable the file was uploaded to.

[image: Screenshot showing File Preview option]

Comment: Thank you. I am using the comunity version and not sure if file preview is available in it. Anyway, thekind of preview I needed is a "in page preview" without having to click any buttons.

Comment: The file preview automatically displays "in page" upon screen load. No clicking necessary.